# How do i identify parameters function of md5sum of specific binary?

Tags: decompilation, elf, ghidra, binary, openssl

So, i downloaded the binary. Here are some details before moving forward:

`revbinary: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=2f0bc3cfa6ec6a297f58ae75f8802bd1b5ef7162, not stripped`

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffec358000)
        libmariadb.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadb.so.3 (0x00007f1d76fbe000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f1d76cd2000)
        libzip.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so.4 (0x00007f1d76cb7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1d76af2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1d76ad0000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1d76ab3000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1d76aab000)
        libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f1d768e1000)
        libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f1d768ce000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1d7703c000)
        libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f1d7679a000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f1d76779000)
        libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f1d765f5000)
        libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f1d765df000)
        libnettle.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x00007f1d7659f000)
        libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x00007f1d76556000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f1d764d3000)
        libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f1d764c7000)
```

So, as you can see it depends upon `libcrypto.so` which is i think openssl library. Now debugging a a function called from main, named `process_data` has this code as ghidra gave with some modification: [process_data_code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/716265091489595473/761480880060366848/mysql_zip.c)

Now, i know upto md5 part that it get data from message table and stores a row....... So, i came to md5sum part, its passing the variables to md5sum but i dont know what are the functions of md5sum parameters. If it were libc functions like snprintf or fputs i could see manpage or try googling but it didnt give me nice results. This stackoverflow answer

[image: Stackoverflow] says the first parameter is password, second is length of password
and third is some weird shit. So, if you see the code you will get md5sum has 4 parameters

`md5sum(random_mysql_rows_bufarray,mysql_rows_buffer_length & 0xffffffff, filename_ofvarlocal, mysql_rows_buffer_length & 0xffffffff);`

Also, that answer says md5sum having 4 parameter isnt openssl md5. I just want to figure out what is the function of those 4 parameters in md5sum. Also if you could explain what is the weird `& 0xfffffff` thing then it would be great! Here's the binary : [reverse binary](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/716265091489595473/761489241875808266/revbinary)

Yeah, md5sum takes 4 parameter, got it.

Comment: remove the image and link the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947393/in-which-library-is-the-md5-function)  and according  to that query it was a mistake and was edited later to show only three arguments openssl.md5sum takes 3 arguments only remove words that are not usable in a public site from your query thethird argument is a pointer to the returned hashvalue a char buffer[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file command says the binary is unstripped you shouldn't have much problem identifying the arguments

the &0xffffffff is a mask to get a 32 bit value from a 64 bit value

for example if a function is proto typed as `ulong64 foo(ulong64 a, ulong b);`

as x64 calling convention uses 6 registers in linux system ABI  [RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437191/function-parameters-transferred-in-registers-on-64bit-os)  you cannot simply pass rsi without zeroing the upper 32 bits

the & 0xffffffff zeros the upper 32 bits of 64 bit register

```
>>> a = 0x123456789abcdef0
>>> b = a & 0xffffffff
>>> print("val32=%016x\nval64=%016x\n" % (b,a))
val32=000000009abcdef0
val64=123456789abcdef0
```

if the line you pasted is from ghidra then ghidra might be mistaking the use of a register you can over ride the function signature